# How do you actually print the description that a Python ROS launch file describes?

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, launch-file, ros-galactic

Launch files in ROS 2 written in Python are actually generating a launch description that something else uses to launch the system, as opposed to launching things themselves (see [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/why-does-the-ros2-python-launch-files-look-like-xml-written-in-python/23679/18)). It would be useful to see what the generated description actually is so that we can debug the Python launch files.

There already seems like there's a command to do this `ros2 launch -p <packge_name> <launch_file_name>` (see [here](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/rolling/ros2launch/ros2launch/command/launch.py#L84)), however the output it actually generates is not too useful, e.g.:

```
<launch.launch_description.LaunchDescription object at 0x7f6a2e445490>
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2f026220>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2f026520>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2f00df40>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2f059760>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fc4c0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fc700>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fc790>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fc8b0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fc910>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fc9a0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fca30>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcac0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcb50>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcbe0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcca0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcd60>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fc0a0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fce80>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcf10>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcfa0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcd00>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e3fcdf0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf130>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf0a0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf1c0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf2e0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf370>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf400>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf490>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf1f0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf5b0>')
├── Action('<launch.actions.declare_launch_argument.DeclareLaunchArgument object at 0x7f6a2e4cf640>')
├── ExecuteProcess(cmd=['ros2', 'bag', 'record', '--all', '-o', './bags/20231110-043600_bag'], cwd=None, env=None, shell=False)
└── Action('<launch.actions.group_action.GroupAction object at 0x7f6a2e445640>')
```

Is there a way to show what the GroupAction does, (and included launch files) recursively?
If this generates an XML format under the hood, is there a way to show that?